# Always return focus to a specific input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, setfocus

I do not think this exact question has an answer anywhere else.

I have a page with a couple of input fields, and lots of ajax activity for various things. It is an online POS interface. When any of the ajax actions are performed, ususally by a button click, it is desired to always return focus to the main barcode input field.

Whilst this can be done by always calling $('#fieldid').focus() after any of these actions, I was wondering if there was a way of specifying that this field should always have focus after any action.  There are other input fields where you need to type a name or something so obviously it cannot just set a timer and set focus on timeout as you would need to allow time for typing.

One option would be to have a timer always running to do it, and constantly reset it when typing. This seems to perhaps be sensible as these fields do have live search on typing associated with them.

Maybe I have answered my own question here, but any better way of doing it would bt greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be honest this feels like a very specific so I'd be very surprised if it actually existed. Your best bet would be to ID them similarly, then use some CSS selector magic to target them all using JQuery and then call the focus like you typed.

Comment: that sounds like it could break tab-navigation and thus accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the focus trigger within your callback, after appending the html?

Example:

```
$.post(
    'ajax.php',
    { next:next },
    function(data){
        $('body').append($(data).hide().fadeIn('slow'));
        $('textarea').focus();
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for this, but this is basically what I have been doing, and it works, but I have to remember to do it for each ajax call I add to the system

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeated code for each ajax call,

use ajaxStop event.

```
$.ajaxStop(function(){
    $('textarea').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preventDefault(); function in Javascript